# InteractiveViewer scrolling mouse wheel should zoom in and out but it scrolls up and down

Tags: flutter

I'm using the [GraphView](https://pub.dev/packages/graphview) package to implement a graph inside a `InteractiveViewer` element. For demonstration purposes, I'm using the [example](https://github.com/nabil6391/graphview/blob/master/example/lib/tree_graphview.dart) of the package, here is the code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:graphview/GraphView.dart';

class TreeViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TreeViewPageState createState() => _TreeViewPageState();
}

class _TreeViewPageState extends State<TreeViewPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Wrap(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: builder.siblingSeparation.toString(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Sibling Separation'),
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      builder.siblingSeparation = int.tryParse(text) ?? 100;
                      this.setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: builder.levelSeparation.toString(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Level Separation'),
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      builder.levelSeparation = int.tryParse(text) ?? 100;
                      this.setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: builder.subtreeSeparation.toString(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Subtree separation'),
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      builder.subtreeSeparation = int.tryParse(text) ?? 100;
                      this.setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: builder.orientation.toString(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Orientation'),
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      builder.orientation = int.tryParse(text) ?? 100;
                      this.setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    final node12 = Node.Id(r.nextInt(100));
                    var edge = graph.getNodeAtPosition(r.nextInt(graph.nodeCount()));
                    print(edge);
                    graph.addEdge(edge, node12);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: Text('Add'),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                  constrained: false,
                  boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                  minScale: 0.01,
                  maxScale: 5.6,
                  child: GraphView(
                    graph: graph,
                    algorithm: BuchheimWalkerAlgorithm(builder, TreeEdgeRenderer(builder)),
                    paint: Paint()
                      ..color = Colors.green
                      ..strokeWidth = 1
                      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
                    builder: (Node node) {
                      // I can decide what widget should be shown here based on the id
                      var a = node.key!.value as int?;
                      return rectangleWidget(a);
                    },
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Random r = Random();

  Widget rectangleWidget(int? a) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print('clicked');
      },
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(color: Colors.blue[100]!, spreadRadius: 1),
            ],
          ),
          child: Text('Node ${a}')),
    );
  }

  final Graph graph = Graph()..isTree = true;
  BuchheimWalkerConfiguration builder = BuchheimWalkerConfiguration();

  @override
  void initState() {
    final node1 = Node.Id(1);
    final node2 = Node.Id(2);
    final node3 = Node.Id(3);
    final node4 = Node.Id(4);
    final node5 = Node.Id(5);
    final node6 = Node.Id(6);
    final node8 = Node.Id(7);
    final node7 = Node.Id(8);
    final node9 = Node.Id(9);
    final node10 = Node.Id(10);
    final node11 = Node.Id(11);
    final node12 = Node.Id(12);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node3, paint: Paint()..color = Colors.red);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node4, paint: Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node5);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node6);
    graph.addEdge(node6, node7, paint: Paint()..color = Colors.red);
    graph.addEdge(node6, node8, paint: Paint()..color = Colors.red);
    graph.addEdge(node4, node9);
    graph.addEdge(node4, node10, paint: Paint()..color = Colors.black);
    graph.addEdge(node4, node11, paint: Paint()..color = Colors.red);
    graph.addEdge(node11, node12);

    builder
      ..siblingSeparation = (100)
      ..levelSeparation = (150)
      ..subtreeSeparation = (150)
      ..orientation = (BuchheimWalkerConfiguration.ORIENTATION_TOP_BOTTOM);
  }
}
```

This exact example is also hosted here: https://graphview.surge.sh/#/

Now my problem is when running my app on the web, scrolling my mouse wheel will scroll the page up and down. When I scroll the mouse wheel in the hosted example, it zooms in and out, which is the behavior I want to achieve too.

Why does my mouse wheel not scroll in and out? I'm using the exact same code as the example. I'm on flutter 3.10, I'm not sure what version the hosted example uses, maybe there was a change with a newer flutter version?